# Remotely accesing file from java

Tags: java, date, remote-access

I am working at an application in java from windows. I have to connect to a server. I only know the ip: 172.... and port. I want to obtain the last modified date for a file on that server. I have tried some methods but it doesn't work. I read a lot about http, ftp, sftp but this things are not clear for me, and i could not understand how to obtain the date. Please help me!
I have tried with urlConnection, with ftp etc..

Comment: what is the error you are getting with URLConnection? what have you tried and where are you failing also check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416872/how-do-you-obtain-modified-date-from-a-remote-file-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416872/how-do-you-obtain-modified-date-from-a-remote-file-java)

Comment: Read some more, especially on RMI.

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to write that url, i dont know if have to put http, ftp or sftp. I wan to connect the server with a general method..

Comment: There are [standard port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), for the protocols, for instance for FTP 20 and 21. You then could try in the browers: `ftp://172. ...:21/`. If it is a local net, try `\\172. ...\C$` or such.

Comment: There are two problems, first the data transfer protocol. Best when `file:` or `http:`. And secondly the protocol handler: one need specific libraries for some protocols.

Answer (score 0):

On windows the file sharing protocol is CIFS.

You have a java Open source library which implement this protocol : [jcifs](https://jcifs.samba.org/)